# Why is the excel date cell-format, date and time is so low

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

Does anyone have a workaround for formatting datetimes copied from sql into excel?

When I copy a date field into excel from sql, it looks like the following 43299.7088541667, I then want to format it as follows: 7/18/2018  5:00:45 PM

The date time format I pick, DD/MM/YYYY Time is one of the bottom ones to select

This is something I do multiple times a day, does anyone know a quick way/shortcut to do this?

Comment: This question is vague and will probably result in low quality suggestions. Since you mention SQL, how about a data connection and power query to format the date before loading into excel?

Comment: Can you edit your question for more clarity? You have 3 different date formats shown, and it is difficult to tell what exactly you are selecting. Your question tagged SQL, are you looking for an excel solution or SQL solution? Is your issue related to a single cell formatting after copy? Are you looking for a way to move the options in the lists you are selecting from?

Comment: How did you copy to Excel? Directly copy and paste? Did you try to create connection to import the data to Excel?

Comment: if you're copying data manually from a db to Excel then you're doing it wrong. Excel can do it automatically via connections to db

Answer (score 0):

Yes, someone does know a quick way, or two, to do this.

Do you paste with mouse clicks or by hand (`Ctrl-V`, that kind of thing)? If by mouse clicks, you can right click, then in the pasting options area, choose the rightmost of the two options:  `Match Destination Formatting (M)` appears when you hover over the option before clicking.

If you do it by hand, you'd need to press `Alt-E-S`, then down arrow twice to highlight `Text` and Enter to finalize the choice.

Both of those are a little harder than the best option:

Click on the cell you want it to paste into. Press `F2` to edit the formula in the cell (there isn't one, it's empty, but the formula editor is where one would show up if there were a formula).

Immediately press `Ctrl-V` to paste. Then Enter to finalize it.

So, a click, press of `F2`, and pasting with `Ctrl-V-Enter`.

Easy peasey.

Pasting into the formula editor only ever pastes the text on the clipboard. None of any formatting that might come with it like from websites. Not an issue here, but it could be for other times you use the technique.

Since it pastes only the text (that also being the point of the first method I mentioned, above), it will not change your chosen date formatting.

Should mention:  the whole string will paste, so the time information will still be there. That could affect further formulas that might, say, subtract this date from some other date, that kind of thing. So you would need to address those concerns, if any. I am only addressing a quick paste of the data into Excel.

*So, quick and easy.*

Other approaches can work as well. For instance, you might paste the "whatever" string into a different cell, maybe one right next to it, and have a formula in the desired cell (where your formatting is) that reads the pasted datum from the pasting cell and presents it formatted as you like.

Another could be to use VBA to activate upon pasting in that cell that then applies the desired format to the cell, overwriting any formatting that came with it, or any changing Excel did as it "helped you" when you pasted it.

(These last two ways could be pretty unwieldy if you want to paste into lots of cells all over your worksheet.)

*Click on the cell, press `F2`, then `Ctrl-V-Enter` and you're golden.*